# Сложность изучения C++

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос к мэтрам:
Почему C++ считается более сложным в изучении, чем другие ЯП? Чем он будет сложнее в освоении для новичка, чем тот-же C# или Java?

Comment: Потому что ручное управление памятью

Comment: Ручное управление памятью, сложный синтаксис, полные шаблоны, минимальное количество сахара, скудная стандартная библиотека

Comment: Просто вы управляете всем. Указатели, работа с памятью и все это пугает новичка.

Comment: мой первый ЯП -  c++, и я не желею!

Comment: Мое imho - миф. Непонятно кем создаваемый и зачем распускаемый. Опять же - то же ручное управление памятью - это, на мой взгляд, огромное преимущество, а не недостаток. Не скажу, что я так уж горел желанием изучать Java, но пробовал - как по мне, он запутаннее и неочевиднее, в нем нет присущей С++ элегантности - когда пишешь и понимаешь, как именно это будет работать на машине... Еще раз - это **мое личное мнение**, не более того.

Comment: №1) Наличие более чем одного механизма для выполнения одних и тех же задач.  №2) Унаследован от Си(практически придется изучать 2 языка).  №3) Сложный синтаксис и объёмная спецификация языка.  №4) Сложная и постоянно разрастающаяся стандартная библиотека, И т.д. но в итоге вы лучне представляете "как все устроено " и обладаете  более широкими  возможностями

Comment: @Harry именно из-за необходимости досканального понимания работы C++ сложен и неудобен. Программист должен решать бизнес-задачу, а не сидеть и думать над тем, что как работает. Думать над работой за него должен компилятор (и рантайм со сборщиком мусора, если они есть).

Comment: @andreymal Я уже написал, что это мое личное мнение; вы можете считать так, как сочтете нужным. Программисты и так в последнее время - сужу по ruSO :) - переложили на компилятор все, даже обязанность думать :)

Comment: [Почитайте](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/), там много чего объясняют (ручное управление памятью и скудная стандартная библиотека к делу не имеют никакого отношения)

Answer (score -3):

C++ дает программисту множество возможностей, а чем больше возможностей, тем сложнее. Некоторые вещи (например возможноть присваивания внутри условия if) очень часто являются ошибками или опечатками (хоть и не всегда), но c++ об этом не сообщает и можно долго провозиться, пытаясь обнаружить такую ошибку.

Некоторые вещи могут показаться нелогичными новичку. Например, 3 / 2 будет равно 1, а не 1.5 (если предварительно не "сказать", что требуется нецелый результат). А 2000000000 + 2000000000 = -294967296.

Также в C++ достаточно сложно начать разрабатывать такие вещи, как графика, взаимодействие с чем-либо вне программы и др. Т.к. большинство этих задач не решается стандартными средствами языка.

Comment: Все это как раз просто. Сложности начнаются, например, [вот в таких случаях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1082520/232), при перегрузке функций (и особенно вводе своих операций с классами, что в принципе вещи одной природы), неоднозначности с templates (особенно при попытках библиотечной реализации) и др. типично крестовых подходах к ООП