# Виды и правила инициализации в C++

Tags: c++, инициализация

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
struct Object
{
    Object() : i{ 0 }
    {
    };
    int i;
    int j;
};

// ...

Object object_1;
Object object_2{};
```

Как я понимаю, происходит следующее:

- Поля объекта `object_1` имеют следующие значения: `i == 0`, `j == undefined value`;
- Поля объекта `object_2` имеют следующее значения: `i == 0`, `j == 0`.

Все действительно так?

Я зачитал `Стандарт`, пытаясь понять логику различных видов инициализации в `C++`, но запутался окончательно. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет доходчиво объяснить, какие виды инициализации существуют, и каким правилам эти виды подчиняются.

Comment: Нет, в случае 2 j == undefined

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/469465/ https://habr.com/ru/post/438492/ вроде материал один и тот же в ссылках, но одна с видео

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, здесь разницы между `Object object_1;` и `Object object_2{};` нет. В обоих объектах `j` не инициализирован.

Разница появляется, когда конструктор по умолчанию либо сгенерирован компилятором, либо отмечен как `=default` в теле класса:

```
struct Object
{
    // Здесь ничего не меняет:
    // Object() = default;

    int i = 42;
    int j;
};
```

Здесь да, `j` инициализируется нулем только для `Object object_2{};`.

---

> Я зачитал Стандарт, пытаясь понять логику различных видов инициализации

Я бы вот тут почитал: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization